# Uppercase after every character in NP++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to turn every letter after `:` to uppercase on every single line.

For example from:

```
nerd:class:ace
make:milk
lake:cake
```

to

```
nerd:Class:Ace
make:Milk
lake:Cake
```

Comment: We need more specifics.  What language are you working with?  What code have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open `Replace` menu with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
2. Ensure the `Regular expression` checkbox is ticked.
3. Enter `:([a-z])` in the `Find what :` field (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>). This matches and captures any letter following a `:`.
4. Enter `:\U$1` in the `Replace with :` field (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>). `\U` uppercases the captured letter in the matched group `$1`.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to `Replace All`.

Comment: May I ask what would happen if the capture group had more than one letter in it?  Would `cat` become `Cat` or `CAT`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if the capture group is `([a-z]+)`, `\U$1` gives you `CAT`.